# Get the result at the right time with node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

i am new to node.js, i followed some tutorial.

I don't know how to get the array "result" only when the call in the function end.

```
app.get('/api/email/check/:email',function (request,response){
    var email = request.params['email'];
    var result = Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        existence.check(email, function(err,res){
            result[i]=res; console.log({"Result":res});
        });

    };
    response.send(result); // Problem is that i get: [] 
});
```

I got the log but the result is an empty array because it's called before the functions ends. Is there a nice way to resolve this ? without counting the "i".

Comment: Why are you calling `existence.check()` twice in a row with exactly the same argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can put

response.send(result);

out of the for loop.

Because response.send() is a async method so before the for loop ends,  response has ended before.

Comment: was my mistake. I update the code on the topic. But it's the same result, empty array :(

Comment: Then where is the existence.check method from?You need to check whether  it is an async method.

Comment: yes it's asynchronous. it's a dependency: "email-existence":"0.x"

Comment: Then it is easy. You can use Async module to control the workflow in order to make sure the response.send is called only after all the existence.check have been called and return.